# Nested List to Array Mapping in AutoMapper

Tags: list, nested, mapping, automapper

The below classes in Domain Emtity:

```
    public class SecondaryCustomerProfile
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public List<SecondaryCustomerProfileProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondaryCustomerProfileProductType
    {
        public int IdField { get; set; }
        public int SecondaryCustomerProfileIdField { get; set; }
        public string TypeField { get; set; }
    }

    //The following class in WCF Service

    public class SecondaryCustomerProfile 
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public SecondaryCustomerProfileProductType[] ProductTypes { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondaryCustomerProfileProductType
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public int SecondaryCustomerProfileIdField { get; set; }
        public string Type{ get; set; }
    }
```

Now when I am trying to map as following...

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Core.DomainEntities.SecondaryCustomerProfile, Core.CustomerService.SecondaryCustomerProfile>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
    .ForMember(d => d.ProductTypes, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.ProductTypes));

Mapper.CreateMap<Core.DomainEntities.SecondaryCustomerProfileProductType, Core.CustomerService.SecondaryCustomerProfileProductType>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.IdField))
    .ForMember(d => d.SecondaryCustomerProfileId, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.SecondaryCustomerProfileIdField))
    .ForMember(d => d.Type, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.TypeField));

Mapper.Map<DomainEntities.SecondaryCustomerProfile, CustomerService.SecondaryCustomerProfile>(profile);
```

I am getting error:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233088
Message=Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
SecondaryCustomerProfile -> SecondaryCustomerProfile
DomainEntities.SecondaryCustomerProfile -> CustomerService.SecondaryCustomerProfile

Destination path:
SecondaryCustomerProfile

Source value:
DomainEntities.SecondaryCustomerProfile
  Source=AutoMapper
  StackTrace:
       at Services\Customer\CustomerCoreService.cs:line 75
       at CustomerController.Save(List`1 secondaryCustomerProfileModels) in C:\Test\CustomerController.cs:line 99
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException: 
.
```

Comment: Please give the exact error message.

Comment: Error : {"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.}

Comment: The error should give more details. Please edit it into your question.

Comment: Stack error details is given

Comment: Now you undid my previous edit :( A well-formatted question is answered much sooner than a maze of text. Anyway, you're missing a mapping for `SecondaryCustomerProfile`.

Comment: What type of mapping I am missing...I could not understand....

Comment: After completing your mapping setup, add a call to  `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`.  That will make sure you've got everything mapped properly and will identify any issues.

Comment: Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() is there. But I don't know what is the issue.

Comment: var obj = Mapper.Map<DomainEntities.SecondaryCustomerProfileProductType, CustomerService.SecondaryCustomerProfileProductType>(productTypeObj);  Even this mapping is also not working.

Comment: When CreateMap code is placing in the sevice layer method then mapping is working fine...but if the Mapper.CreateMap method is exist in separate File and register in Global.asax file, then maooing is not working